# SharePoint 2013 - open a modal dialog form by clicking an image on the page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, modal-dialog, image

I would like to open up a user form in a pop-up window by clicking on an image in the page.

I have tried adding code to the source editor, but it just gets stripped.

There is much talk of SP.UI.ModalDialog being the solution. However, I am very new to Sharepoint and would not know where or how to apply this.

Could anyone share an example of where a pop-up form is opened on the click of an image?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code in `Script Editor Web Part`

```
<script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Title of the Dialog',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 500,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://url');"><img src="mqassas.gif"></a>
```

---

- At `<img src="mqassas.gif">`, set the image URL ,and to be clickable it would be added within `<a>` tag
- At `onclick="openDialog('http://url');"`,  set the URl that you need to shown in Modal Dialog

Check the detail steps at [open a SharePoint link via SharePoint Modal](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Comment: Wow that's nearly perfect! I just need to try and work out the url of the image and it will be exactly what I am after.  Thanks!!

Comment: Take your time, Hope it helps you!

Comment: Got it! Used good old F12. I will mark as correct answer.

Comment: Is there an additional function to close the modal when you click anywhere outside the window?